# Ruby on Rails: Uninitialized Constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a question about accessing custom classes from a controller in my Ruby on Rails Project.

I am following this [tutorial](http://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/using-the-google-api-ruby-client-with-google-calendar-api/) about integrating Google Calendar API with my Rails app and part of the section is to create a `GoogleCalendarWrapper`. I created this file in `lib/google_cal_wrapper.rb`, however I get the error:

`uninitialized constant EventsController::GoogleCalWrapper`

Here is my code in `events_controller`

```
  def index
    if user_signed_in?
      @event = current_user.posts.build
      @calendar = GoogleCalWrapper.new(current_user)

      # response = @client.execute(api_method: @service.calendar_list.list)
      # calendars = JSON.parse(response.body)
      # puts(calendars)
    #  @places = Classroom.all.map { |x| x.name }
    else
      @event = Event.new
    end
end
```

-

```
#lib/google_cal_wrapper.rb
class GoogleCalWrapper
  def initialize(current_user)
    configure_client(current_user)
  end
  def configure_client(current_user)
    @client = Google::APIClient.new
    @client.authorization.access_token = current_user.token
    @client.authorization.refresh_token = current_user.refresh_token
    puts @client.authorization.refresh_token
    @client.authorization.client_id = ENV['GOOGLE_KEY']
    @client.authorization.client_secret = ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET']
    @client.authorization.refresh!
    @service = @client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')

  end
end
```

--Some extra info:

`

```
#omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
  def google_oauth2
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user
    else
      session["devise.google_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"].except("extra")
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

#user.rb
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    user = where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.avatar = auth.info.image # assuming the user model has an image
    end
    user.token = auth.credentials.token
    user.refresh_token = auth.credentials.refresh_token
    if user.valid?
      puts "#{user} saved"
    else
      puts user.errors.full_messages
    end
    return user
  end
```

Comment: Try `::GoogleCalWrapper.new(current_user)`

Comment: Good idea! I just tried and it narrowed the error to: `uninitialized constant GoogleCalWrapper`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't particularly like the name `Wrapper` for this class, but hey, that's not the point here.

If I were you, I would put a `wrappers` folder under `app` and then put `google_cal_wrapper.rb` in that folder. So you end up with:

```
app
 |- assets
 |- controllers
 |- ...
 |- wrappers
     |- google_cal_wrapper.rb
```

That way it should be autoloaded and available within your controller as simply `GoogleCalWrapper`.

BTW, in my projects where I use the `google-api-client` (and other api clients), I call these sort of things `services` and my directory structure looks something like (naturally, replacing `app_name` and `AppName` with the actual name I am using for my current app):

```
app
 |- assets
 |- controllers
 |- ...
 |- services
 |   |- app_name
 |   |   |- service_base.rb
 |   |- google
 |   |   |- calendar
 |   |   |   |- list_service.rb
 |   |   |- calendar_service.rb
 |   |   |- client_service.rb
 |   |   |- service_base.rb
 |   |- quickbooks
 |   |  |- consumer_service.rb
 |   |  |- service_base.rb
 |   |- ...
 |- ...
```

And my classes look something like:

```
class AppName::ServiceBase

  attr_accessor *%w(
    args
  ).freeze

  # allows you to call Google::Service.call(current_user: current_user)
  # without having to do Google::Service.new(current_user: current_user)
  # which I prefer.
  class << self
    def call(args={})
      new(args).call
    end
  end # Class Methods

  #==================================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #==================================================================================

    def initialize(args={})
      @args = args
      assign_args
    end

  private

    # creates an attr_accessor for each k,v pair in args. So,
    # for instance, when called like 
    # Google::Service.call(current_user: current_user),
    # the new service instance will have a method called
    # 'current_user' that returns the current_user
    def assign_args
      args.each do |k,v| 
        class_eval do 
          attr_accessor k
        end
        send("#{k}=",v)
      end
    end    

end
```

A base class for the Google classes:

```
class Google::ServiceBase < AppName::ServiceBase

  private

    def client
      @client ||= Google::ClientService.call(current_user: current_user)
    end

    def calendar_service
      @calendar_service ||= Google::CalendarService.call(current_user: current_user)
    end

end
```

A class that configures a calendar_service

```
class Google::CalendarService < Google::ServiceBase

  #==================================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #==================================================================================

    def call
      client.discovered_api('calendar', 'v3')
    end

end
```

A class that configures a google client

```
class Google::ClientService < Google::ServiceBase

  delegate *%w(
    token
    refresh_token
  ), to: :current_user

  #==================================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #==================================================================================

    def call
      [
        :token,
        :refresh_token,
        :client_id 
        :client_secret
      ].each do |client_attribute|
        client.authorization.send("#{client_attribute}=", send(client_attribute))
      end
      client.authorization.refresh!      
      client
    end

  private

    def client 
      @client ||= Google::APIClient.new
    end

    def client_id
      ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID']
    end

    def client_secret
      ENV['GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET']
    end

end
```

A class for grabbing the calendars_list

```
class Google::Calendar::ListService < Google::ServiceBase

  #==================================================================================
  # Instance Methods
  #==================================================================================

    def call
      # do some stuff like you have commented out in your controller
      # like (naturally, insert code that actually works):
      calendar_service.calendar_list.list
    end

end
```

So you could do something in your `controller` like:

```
def index
  if user_signed_in?
    @event = current_user.posts.build
    @calendar_list = Google::Calendar::ListService.call(current_user: current_user)
  else
    @event = Event.new
  end
end
```

And now your controller doesn't need to know anything about `JSON.parse` or `response` or `.execute` or anything other than `Google::Calendar::ListService.call(current_user: current_user)`.

Comment: Worked, thank you! I thought it was an awkward name too, do you have a better suggestion for this class name?

Comment: Is this updated answer tested? looks good, but for some reason, the Appname::ServiceBase is uninitialized

Comment: I use code like this all the time. As I said in the answer, `app_name` and `AppName` are just place holders. You should replace with something meaningful to you.

Comment: Should've clarified, I replaced `app_name` with `helloU` and `AppName` `HelloU` when I should have made `app_name` -> `hello_u` (which fixed that).

Comment: This did give me `unexpected '<' class < self ^ ` in `hello_u/service_base.rb` and I'm tinkering with it to figure out why. But this answer definitely deserves an award and I appreciate you sharing your approach

Comment: Sorry, should be `class << self`, updated answer. BTW, putting `def` statements inside `class << self` is an alternative way for defining class methods (as opposed to `def self.call`).

Comment: Yup, came to the same conclusion just now (thanks to your comment). And now trying to debug `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`  for `def call` in `google/calendar_service.rb`

Comment: Ugh. Repurposing code here. See updated to correct that error. (Should have been `new(args).call`, not `new.call(args)`).

Comment: Deleted my last comment because I overlooked your comment.  I am arriving at `undefined method token=' for #<Signet::OAuth2::Client:0x00007fea5b7995f8> Did you mean? id_token=` I suspect it is related to an issue that my `User.from_omniauth(auth)` does not pick up the refresh_token from auth response. I will attach that method to the original question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170306/discussion-between-jvillian-and-marko-calvocruz).